# Range with chars or strings in Python arrays

Tags: python, arrays

i am pretty new to python coming from Java, C, and Haskell environment, i was wondering if there exist something similar to the following but with strings and not numbers, so i have:

```
for i in range(5,11)
    print "Index : %d" %i
```

and the result will be: 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 (each in a new line of course).  So, i want to have the same for strings, like:

```
for c in range("a","e")
    print "Alphabet : %s" %c
```

I am just curious and I have tried many things with both strings and chars but i could not obtain the result I want.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not clear what result you expect. What is the result you want?

Comment: I assume he asks if python will understand that he wants the ASCII symbols between the two parameters. Can't test it right now,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are iterable in Python, so you can simply do:

```
for c in 'abcde':
    print 'Alphabet:', c

Alphabet: a
Alphabet: b
Alphabet: c
Alphabet: d
Alphabet: e
```

If you want an alternative with an explicit `range`, there's the (rather ugly):

```
for c in range(ord('a'), ord('e')+1):
     print 'Alphabet:', chr(c)

Alphabet: a
Alphabet: b
Alphabet: c
Alphabet: d
Alphabet: e
```

`range` does not take strings as arguments in Python, so you have to convert the characters to their ASCII equivalents and then back again.

Answer (score 1):

*Python 2* If you want to print only a range of the `Alphabet` you can not use `range()` for strings. you can only use it for `integers`, but you can do this:

```
Alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
x = Alphabet[5:11]
print "Alphabet : %s" % x
```

The output is:

```
Alphabet : fghijk
```

If you want each string in a new line:

```
for i in x:
    print i
```

Output:

```
f
g
h
i
j
k
```

*In Python 3 you would print like this*:`print(i)`